# Write results from variable loop into sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write the months from today until September into my Excel sheet using a macro. Here is part of the code I have a problem with:

```
Dim months(1 To 12) As String

For i = m To 9
  months(i) = i    
  Cells(31 + i, 6) = MonthName(months(i))
Next i
```

The code basically works, but the problem is that the first cell in the excel spreadsheet varies with the value of i. For example, if today is March, the first cell will be (34,6), but if it is April it will be (35,6).

Can anybody give me a hint how to "fix" the first cell?

Comment: Welcome. Please tell us what should be the cell for the first month (month of today's date) and in which direction -- horizontal or vertical -- the next month should be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The cell of the first month does not matter, but for example F31. Horizontal will be fine.

Comment: Then use `Cells(31 + i - m, 6) = MonthName(months(i))` in your loop.

Comment: That is by far "easier" as I thought. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure your code is fully provided, but if it is then the assign statement could be as well `Cells(31 + i - m, 6) = MonthName(i)` and the previous line may be useless, as well as the string array `months`. Also if today's month is October, your loop will not work as expected.

Comment: I corrected the things you noted. To account for months after September, I work with an if statement. I applied your solution for the first if-clause to the second. Here is the full code:

Sub GetMonths()

m = month(Now)
y = year(Now)
y2 = y + 1

If m <= 9 Then

      For i = m To 9
      Cells(12 + i - m, 7) = MonthName(i) & y
    Next

End If

If m > 9 Then

       
    For i = m To 12
      Cells(12 + i - m, 7) = MonthName(i) & y
    Next i
    
    For j = 1 To 9
      Cells(12 + j + 12 - m, 7) = MonthName(j) & y2
    Next j
    
End If
    
          
End Sub

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use something like this and avoid looping/using an array:

```
Sub SO()

Const startColumn As String = "F" '// Change as required
Const noMonths As Integer = 9 '// Number of months required

With Range(startColumn & "31").Resize(1, noMonths)
    .Formula = "=TEXT(DATEVALUE(""01-""&COLUMN()-" & Range(startColumn & "1").Column - 1 & "&""-2015""),""Mmmm"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```